# "An inline collection of ComboBoxItem" in a DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) says:

> To populate the drop-down list, first set the ItemsSource property for
>   the ComboBox by using one of the following options:
>
> - A static resource. For more information, see StaticResource Markup Extension.
> - An x:Static code entity. For more information, see x:Static Markup Extension.
> - An inline collection of ComboBoxItem types.

With "**An inline collection of ComboBoxItem types**" I thought about something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="None" Tag="0" />
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Few" Tag="1" />
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Some" Tag="2" />
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Enough" Tag="3" />
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Lots" Tag="4" />
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Too much" Tag="5" />
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But it doesn't works. I know about another methods to populate the DataGridComboBoxColumn, but I'm curious about that, this because I find nothing about that in my research... What means "inline collection of ComboBoxItem types" then?

Answer (score 4):

Key thing here is that `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not a `ComboBox` and the cited documentation fragment does not apply.

The reason for why you cannot add `ComboBoxItem` elements in the column definition is, I think, that it would pose the problem of adding them to the visual tree multiple times (upon populating each `ComboBox` those items would be "reused" rather than cloned).

As far as I know though, `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is just a column definition which exposes a few `ComboBox` properties and is by default displayed as a `ComboBox`. My point is, there's no extra functionality to it that cannot be achieved with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Here's an alternative take that should get you started:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="None" Tag="0" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Few" Tag="1" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Some" Tag="2" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Enough" Tag="3" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Lots" Tag="4" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Too much" Tag="5" />
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As opposed to previous scenario this time it works because `ComboBoxItem` elements are defined inside a `DataTemplate`, which means that XAML processor actually translates them into a `FrameworkElementFactory` objects, which in turn are capable of spawning templated `ComboBoxItem` elements on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CompositeCollection` inside `ItemsSource`.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="None" Tag="0" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Few" Tag="1" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Some" Tag="2" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Enough" Tag="3" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Lots" Tag="4" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Too much" Tag="5" />
                </CompositeCollection>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```